# Wix: ImageFile attribute for Progressbar not working

Tags: wix

in my setup project I'd like to customize the Progressbar and give it a different color. I use the default theme xml. This is the progress page i modified:

```
<Page Name="Progress">
    <Image X="11" Y="20" Width="485" Height="300" ImageFile="logo.png" Visible="yes"/>
    <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.ProgressHeader)</Text>
    <Text X="11" Y="121" Width="70" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.ProgressLabel)</Text>
    <Text Name="OverallProgressPackageText" X="85" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OverallProgressPackageText)</Text>
    <Progressbar ImageFile=".\test.bmp" Name="OverallCalculatedProgressbar" X="21" Y="168" Width="-21" Height="33" />
    <Button Name="ProgressCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="85" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.ProgressCancelButton)</Button>
</Page>
```

In the Progressbar tag, I added the ImageFile attribute. The file test.bmp is in the same directory as the theme.xml.
The ImageFile help says the following:

> Relative path to an image file for the control. The image must be 4 pixels wide: left pixel is the left side of progress bar, left middle pixel is progress used, right middle pixel is progress unused, right pixel is right side of progress bar. Mutually exclusive with ImageResource and SourceX and SourceY attributes.

The bmp *is* 4 pixels wide (all pixels are black), but the progress bar is still the default windows color (Win7 with Aero: green). I neither use ImageResource nor SourceX and SourceY attributes (as the documentation requires).

Can anyone help me with this? Did I miss something, or did I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely thmutil is failing to load your `.\test.bmp`. Most likely the file is missing. If the file cannot be loaded, it silently skips the failure and will revert back to the system progress bar.

To ensure that the `.\test.bmp` can be found, I would first recommend removing from the `.\` path and then ensure the file is included as a `Payload` in your `BootstrapperApplication` element. For example:

```
<Bundle ...>
   <BootstrapperApplication SourceFile='path\to\ba.dll'>
      <Payload SourceFile='path\to\custom.thm' />
      <Payload SourceFile='path\to\test.bmp' />
   </BoostrapperApplication>
</Bundle>
```

That will add the file `test.bmp` to the list of BootstrapperApplication payloads. If you are using wixstdba, it would look more like:

```
<Bundle ...>
   <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense'>
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication ThemeFile='path\to\custom.thm' />
      <Payload SourceFile='path\to\test.bmp' />
   </BoostrapperApplication>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: Thanks, the bmp could load correct now, colors are visible. But the progressbar is only 1px high although I set the Height attribute to 20. And the help says, the bmp should only be 1px in height. Any ideas what I need to change here?

Comment: I don't immediately see the comment in help about 1px height but I believe that is incorrect. Seems the progress bar image must be the height it is to be drawn.

Comment: You're right, I _thought_ I read this somewhere... Does this mean that the Height attribute is ignored in that case?

Comment: No, you can make the `Height` **smaller** but bigger won't draw the control any larger.